# Cleanest way to close over a counter in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, closure

I haven't spent too much time with CoffeeScript and am trying to have a simple counter:

```
casper.on('step.complete', ( ->
        i = 0
        return (step) ->
            i += 1
            @echo "Step#{ i }"
    )())
```

Which works fine but seems to have a bit too many parenthesis for CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
casper.on 'step.complete', do -> # invoked right away
  i = 0
  -> @echo "Step#{ ++i }" # implicitly returned function
```

Parentheses: None :-)

The `do` keyword is the equivalent of `(-> ...)()`, i.e. it means "invoke the  following function immediately" (it's also useful to avoid closure pitfalls in loops, by the way.)

The `++i` will increment `i` before it's echo'ed, and CoffeeScript has implicit return, so the `return` keyword can be skipped.

Lastly, I left out the `step` function argument, as you're not using it for anything; you're always adding 1. You can always add it back in of course

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly distangle the code and create a named function instead of an anonymous one.

```
step_creator = ->
    i = 0
    return (step) ->
        i += 1
        @echo "Step#{ i }"

casper.on 'step.complete', step_creator()
```

Comment: This is *still* an anonymous function.

Comment: @meagar, one of the functions is no longer anonymous, isn't it?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Both functions are still anonymous. `step_creator = ->` compiles to `step_creator = function() {`, not to `function step_creator() {`.

Comment: @meagar, isn't that an implementation detail? From the perspective of the programmer, he's creating a function named step_creator.

Comment: @WinstonEwert "Anonymous function" *means* something in JavaScript, and by extension, CoffeeScript. It's no more an implementation detail in CoffeeScript than it is in JavaScript; but regardless, saying "It's now a named function instead of an anonymous one" when it *isn't* is still wrong.

Comment: @meagar, some versions of CoffeeScript actually would compile it as a named function, they don't do it now because of bugs in IE. So I submit that it is in fact an implementation detail. From the perspective of the CoffeeScript programmer whether its a named or anonymous javascript function doesn't matter.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I'm really confused about what you're arguing. This answer is still incorrect, regardless of whether this is or isn't an implementation detail. Are you suggesting that, because a statement concerns implementation details, it's OK for that statement to be false? I could say "`true` in CoffeeScript cross-compiles to `false` in JavaScript", which is obviously false, but apparently because that's an implementation detail, I am still "correct"?

Comment: @meagar, I'm saying that what it compiles into is irrelevant. In C++, a for loop compiles into a number of branches and conditions. But that's an implementation detail. It would be silly to claim that C++ doesn't really have a for loop because its compiled into conditions and branches. So I think its equally incorrect to claim that CoffeeScript doesn't have named function simply because they are always compiled into anonymous functions in Javascript.

Comment: @meagar, this is the equivalent of a named function in CoffeeScript. So I see no problem with calling it a named function. Robert wasn't making any sort of statement about how the function would be implemented in Javascript. He's not talking about what it would be cross-compiled as. He's talking about how the code functions in CoffeeScript. It functions by creating a function and giving it a name. The function is not anonymous because it has a name.

Comment: @WinstonEwert As I said, *words mean things*. This isn't a "named function" because there is no such thing in CoffeeScript. There are only anonymous functions. Calling it a "named function" is inventing a new meaning for something that *already has significant meaning*, and it doesn't make it a named function, which *is a real thing which already exists*.

Comment: @meagar, you can argue that. But I don't think that what you argued before. You argued that it wasn't a named function because of what it compiled into javascript. My argument was that I don't care what it compiles into in javascript. What matters is what it mean in CoffeeScript.

Comment: @meagar, I'll agree that it is a bit of a stretch to call this a named function because in CoffeeScript its a function expression assigned to a variable. But I think it a reasonable stretch to make because: 1) its perfectly clear what robert meant, 2) there is no other meaning of named function in CoffeeScript and 3) I can't see any other non-awkward way of stating what he did.

Comment: @meagar, so you can say that you're technically correct to claim that its not a real named function. But at that point I think you are just nitpicking.

Comment: @WinstonEwert It's not nitpicking to say somebody is wrong when they say something that is *wrong*, and if you want to give him a pass because his understanding of what "anonymous function" means is shaky, that's fine. But anonymous functions and named functions *are different*, and they do *different things*, and by calling this a named function he's stating that *named function behaviour* should be available, and it isn't. This isn't just a semantic debate, this is about actual, real, demonstrable incorrectness.

Comment: @WinstonEwert CoffeeScript may transcompile to JavaScript, but that doesn't mean the whole of JavaScript is simple "implementation" to be ignored. Telling somebody they should adopt alternate *incorrect* meanings for JavaScript terms in CoffeeScript is insane.

Comment: @meagar, its clear we aren't going to reach consensus. I've opened a question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191196/coffeescript-and-named-functions, to see what others say. But I would like to say that I'm not trying to give him a pass for not understanding anonymous functions. I think he's using a broader definition of named function then you, I see no evidence that he doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

A further tweak to Flambino's answer  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/24054/27783:

```
casper.on 'step.complete', do (i=0) ->
    -> @echo "Step#{ ++i }"
```

which compiles to:

```
casper.on('step.complete', (function(i) {
  return function() {
    return this.echo("Step" + (++i));
  };
})(0));
```